# Prove $|e^{ix}-1-ix-\cdots-\frac{(ix)^k}{k!}| \leq \frac{|x|^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$

Tags: inequality

I would like to prove 
$|e^{ix}-1-ix-\cdots-\frac{(ix)^k}{k!}| \leq \frac{|x|^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$, which trick can be used?

Comment: Taylor's Theorem. (With an integral form of the remainder, so it's valid for complex-valued functions.)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:use  Maclaurin series expansion of exponential function 
$${ e }^{ ix }=1+ix-\frac { x^{ 2 } }{ 2! } -\frac { i{ x }^{ 3 } }{ 3! } +...+\frac { { \left( ix \right)  }^{ k } }{ k! } +\frac { { \left( ix \right)  }^{ k+1 } }{ \left( k+1 \right) ! } $$

Answer (score 1):

We need to put conditions on $x$. For example, if $x=-i$, then the absolute value of the difference on the left is $\frac{1}{(k+1)!}+\frac{1}{(k+2)!}+\cdots$.

Comment: Surely it was clear he's talking about real $x$?

Comment: It was not clear to me, though the use of $x$ rather than $z$ may be indicative, as is the fact that for general complex $x$ the inequality does not hold.

Comment: I guess clarity is not well-defined - I assumed it _was_ clear to you and you were just being picky. Not so, my apologies. Hmm, one reason it seems clear to me is that if her were allowing complex values of $x$ there'd be no reason to ask about $e^{ix}$ instead of just $e^x$.

Comment: True, that should have also been a clue to me. Here I was being perhaps excessively literal minded.

Answer (score 0):

If you let $f(x)=e^{ix}$ then this follows from Taylor's Theorem. You should note that "mean-value forms" of the remainder aren't valid for complex-valued functions, but the integral form of the remainder is. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulae_for_the_remainder